# Trace of PSD matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite

Let matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be positive semidefinite (PSD). Let $B = V V^T$, where $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Why does the last equality hold in the following?

$$ \mbox{tr} (A B) = \mbox{tr} \left(A V V^T\right) = \mbox{tr} \left(V^T A V\right)$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Once more, this robot should be silent : the question is clear !

Comment: @geetha290krm Please note that my comment was not about the facts you mention.

Answer (score 2):

That's due to the [cyclic property of the trace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property):
$$\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{D}) = \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}) = \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{C}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}) = \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}).$$

Comment: Makes sense, I can't believe I didn't see  **$trace((AV)V^T) = trace(V^T(AV))$**